# Format nightmare

Tags: formatting

I'm writing my thesis first time with LaTeX. I have several headaches with the formatting of the document:

1. One 12pt looks on paper small than normal 12pt font size. Is that something that's known or my on of my settings is overwriting the default size?

   ```
   \documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper, leqno]{report}
       \linespread{1.5}
       \usepackage{geometry}
       \geometry{a4paper, left=30.5mm, right=22.5mm, top=30mm, bottom=20mm}
   ```
2. I had a fancy hdr earlier today and it vanished. Have no idea why or how to bring it back.

   ```
   \pagestyle{fancy}
       \fancyhf{}
       \rhead{Fraud Discovery Using Data Mining}
       \rfoot{Page \thepage}
   ```
3. I had page number starting from the Introduction and they vanished too. I have a TOC and Abstract without page numbers.
4. How do I fix the footer such that it is XX cm from the bottom of the page? Like in word. I have some page with a huge space between the bottom of the footer and the bottom of the page.

Here is the preamble  sorry about it! I'm really new to LaTeX and made a mess of it.

```
    \documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper, leqno]{report}
    \linespread{1.5}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a4paper, left=30.5mm, right=22.5mm, top=30mm, bottom=20mm}
    %\usepackage{times}
    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{scrextend}
    \usepackage{apacite}
    \usepackage{float}
    \setcounter{tocdepth}{4}
    \usepackage{amsfonts}
    \usepackage{tabularx}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \usepackage{eurosym}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usepackage{booktabs}
    \usepackage[flushleft]{threeparttable}
    \usepackage{graphicx}
    %\usepackage{epstopdf}
    \usepackage{url}
    \usepackage[english]{babel}
    \usepackage{multicol} 
    \usepackage{pgf}
    \graphicspath{ {images/} }
    \usepackage{caption}
    \usepackage{boldline}
    \usepackage{pdflscape}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{pgfplots}
    \usepackage{pst-plot}
    \usepackage{pdfpages}
    \usepackage{appendix}
    \usepackage{mathtools}
    \usepackage{array}
    \usepackage{makecell}
    \pgfplotsset{xticklabel={\tick},scaled x ticks=false}
    \pgfplotsset{plot coordinates/math parser=false}
    \pgfplotsset{compat=1.8}
    \usepgfplotslibrary{statistics}
    %\newcommand*{\h}{\hspace{5pt}}% for indentation
    %\newcommand*{\hh}{\h\h}% double indentation
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{pabox}[2][]{colback=black!5!white,colframe=black!75!white,fonttitle=\bfseries, title=Figure \thetcbcounter:#1}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.05em}
    %\pagestyle{fancy}
    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{Fraud Discovery Using Data Mining}
    \rfoot{Page \thepage}


     %Beginning of document:


        \begin{document}  
           % \input{cover_page}
            \thispagestyle{empty}
            \include{abstract}
            \thispagestyle{empty}
            \renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}\pagestyle{empty} 
            \tableofcontents{\protect\thispagestyle{empty} % Table of contents
        \pagestyle{empty} 
        \cleardoublepage
        \pagestyle{plain}
    \section{Intro}
    Researchers have conducted studies in order to develop a deep 
    understanding of fraudulent behavior. We believe understanding the 
    psychological aspects of fraud can be very beneficial for fraud detection 
    and prevention.

\end{document}
```

.

Comment: Usually, size reduction in print is due to an option for scaling down in the printer driver. Check it, please.

Comment: Also check the font used, maybe it just looks smaller because it has a smaller x-height while being technically 12pt.

Comment: egreg, I will check those when I go to print again tomorrow. @ienissei , the document properties in adobe says its on Helvetica bold and light. What does that mean in terms of the x-height or how do i find out. I thought I was using the default settings.

Comment: @ienissei means that not all the fonts nominally at 12pt looks the same size. The x-eight is one of the characteristics of a font (approx the height of a lowcase letter with no ascedent nor descendent) and it changes from font to font.

Comment: really you could vastly simplify your preamble,  you load tikz twice, loading pgf isn't needed as it's loaded by tikz,  you load amsmath twice neither needed as it is loaded by mathtools (which you load twice) you load array twice, neither of which is needed as it is loaded by tabularx, you load graphicx that isn't needed as its loaded by pdflscape. You load pst-plots:  are you really using pstricks and tikz at same time (not impossible but...)

Comment: I think if you uncomment   %\pagestyle{fancy} you will get back your fancy header.

Comment: Also, some pdf readers, when printing, will have settings that shrink the output, I would check that regarding your point size.

Comment: Thanks David Carlisle for this..it clears some of this crazyness. @AFeldman uncommenting %\pagestyle{fancy} didnt help. I need to clear up the header point. I can't even seen the header title and page numbers in the texmaker pdf viewer, which I could see both earlier today. Don't get this at all. Also, how can I fix that the page number (when it will show) and footer line will always be at a fixed height from the bottom of the page?

Comment: the headers will be a fixed position on the page and they will show if you don't put multiple `\pagestye{empty}` and `\pagestyle{plain}` which turn them off, see the answer I posted.

Comment: Nothing in the code you show selected helvetica so the acrobat document properties for the document as posted here can not possibly show helvetica.

Answer (score 3):

[image]

you had defined a fancy page style but commented out the use of that style, and even if it were uncommented you  had over-written it *multiple* times with the empty and plain styles. Also there were several error and unclosed groups reported.

```
  \documentclass[12pt, oneside, a4paper, leqno]{report}
    \linespread{1.5}
    \usepackage{geometry}
    \geometry{a4paper, left=30.5mm, right=22.5mm, top=30mm, bottom=20mm}
    \usepackage[export]{adjustbox}
    \usepackage{fancyhdr}
    \usepackage{tikz}
    \usetikzlibrary{arrows}
    \usepackage{cite}
    \usepackage{tcolorbox}
    \usepackage{amsmath}
    \newtcolorbox[auto counter,number within=section]{pabox}[2][]{colback=black!5!white,colframe=black!75!white,fonttitle=\bfseries, title=Figure \thetcbcounter:#1}

    \setlength{\parindent}{15pt}
    \setlength{\arrayrulewidth}{.05em}

    \fancyhf{}
    \rhead{Fraud Discovery Using Data Mining}%<- this is quite odd, to have fixed head!!
    \rfoot{Page \thepage}
    \pagestyle{fancy}

     %Beginning of document:


        \begin{document}  
            %\input{cover_page}
            \thispagestyle{empty}
            \include{abstract}
%            \thispagestyle{empty}
% no!            \renewcommand\contentsname{Table of Contents}\pagestyle{empty} 
            \tableofcontents
%{\protect\thispagestyle{empty} % Table of contents %% no idea what 
       % \pagestyle{empty} 
        \cleardoublepage
      %  \pagestyle{plain}
    \section{Intro}
    Researchers have conducted studies in order to develop a deep 
    understanding of fraudulent behavior. We believe understanding the 
    psychological aspects of fraud can be very beneficial for fraud detection 
    and prevention.

\end{document}
```

Comment: ! thanks words perfectly !! fancy header is back and page numbers. Two anomalies remain - 1. is the margin at the bottom, i'll illustrate in the original post with screenshots perhaps I didnt articulate myself well enough. 2 - there is a 'space' of almost a whole page but I there is no pagebreak or new chapter in between the end of the text and beginning of the new section.

Comment: @OAK no don't ask multiple questions in one question and don't edit the question to ask new question as it makes the answers meaningless. start from a simpler document and ask separate questions if you have separate issue.

Comment: Ok good point in deed